# How to use Jest with opencCV.js?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, opencv, testing, jestjs

I'm using **jest** and **enzyme** to write tests for my **React** application.
In my App component **opencv.js** is imported. And the test fails. 
This is a simplified version of my component

```
import '../lib/opencv/opencv';

function App () {
  console.log('App');
  return 2;
}

export { App };
```

And here is the test

```
import { App } from './App';

describe('App',() => {
  test('App with opencv.js', () => {
   expect(App().toBe(2));
  });
});
```

this test fails with the following error

```
 FAIL  src/App.test.jsx
 ● Test suite failed to run

ReferenceError: Module is not defined

  28 | 
  29 |   if (typeof Module === 'undefined')
> 30 |     Module = {};
     |           ^
  31 |   return cv(Module);
  32 | }));
  33 | 

  at factory (lib/opencv/opencv.js:30:11)
  at Object.<anonymous>._scriptDir (lib/opencv/opencv.js:3:13)
  at Object.<anonymous> (lib/opencv/opencv.js:2:2)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.jsx:1:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.test.jsx:1:1)
```

if I comment this line

```
import '../lib/opencv/opencv';
```

the test will pass.

How should I write tests for the component where I import OpenCV?

Versions

react: ^16.8.3,

jest: ^24.9.0,

babel-jest: ^24.9.0,

opencv.js: 3.4.3

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to rewrite your import line this way:

```
import cv from '../lib/opencv/opencv';
```